how to specialize template using enable_if_t to accept int to enum conversion
I'm trying to write a specialized constructor that would accept integer argument and converted it to enum. My attempt is below, but it fails with an error. Other template candidates are rejected, and they should. Any idea how to fix it ?
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class SomeType
{
public:
    T val;

    template <typename U>
        SomeType<T>(typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type _u) : 
        val(T(_u)) { }
    SomeType<T>(const T& _t) : val(_t) { }
    SomeType<T>(const SomeType<T>& _t) : val(_t.val) { }
    SomeType<T>() : val() { }
};

void foo()
{
    typedef enum { ala=0, ola} MyEnumType;
    SomeType<int> s1;     // OK
    SomeType<int> s2(2);  // OK
    SomeType<MyEnumType> e1;   // OK
    SomeType<MyEnumType> e2(MyEnumType::ola);  // OK
    SomeType<MyEnumType> e3(MyEnumType(0));  // OK
    SomeType<MyEnumType> e4(0); 
        // ERROR: 
        // candidate: template<class U> SomeType<T>::SomeType(typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value, void>::type::type)
        // SomeType<T>(typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type _u) : val(NativeType(_u)) { }
    // ^~~~~~~~~~~
    // template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    // couldn't deduce template parameter 'U'
}

I tried different usage patterns for enable_if_t, but none of them worked

The templated ctor doesn't seem to have a means to pass the type U  to _u.

Something like this: template <typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type> SomeType(U _u) : val(T(_u)) { } Demo. The important part is taking enable_if out of the parameter list; your version places U into non-deduced context.

Thx Igor for an explanation.
